# Why Memory Access Violation error when application outside C:\Program Files

Tags: windows, visual-c++, memory, catia

We have been getting reports of a CAD application (64 bits) crashing multiple times during their sessions with a Memory Access Violation 0xc0000005 error on multiple PCs. I had doubts that it was a hardware issue.

I noticed that the application was installed right under C:\; so I've tried several things (installing other VC++ libraries, etc...) and the last thing I did was uninstalling the CAD application and installing it under C:\Program Files. After that there were no more crashes.

I don't understand why this is working, because I had doubts that there was an actual need to be installing any 64 bits applications under C:\Program Files\ unless you need to install a 32 bits application under C:\Program Files (x86). Can someone explain?

Comment: My only guess is `C:\Program Files` is a part of a hardcoded path that this program expects to find a file and when this poorly written program (assuming my guess is correct) does not find the file in the expected location it crashes instead of issuing an error message to the user.

Comment: Also I do not believe this question is on topic for StackOverflow since you do not have the source code for the CAD program.

Comment: Could also mean the CAD program is "fouling its own nest", i.e., writing into the directory it was installed in.  UAC has a compatibility layer that allows such programs to work, but it is only in play for writes into Program Files and Program Files (x86).